# How to change value of an input field after SQL query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input

I created an input field where a user can type the name of his or her city and after typing minimum 3 characters a SQL query is executed and a dropdown list is created where the user should be able to select one of the cities shown.
As soon as one city is clicked, the value of the input field should be changed to the city the user clicked on.

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" id="Stadt_suche">
<div id="dropdown-content">

</div>
```

And this is script for the database query and filling the input:

```
$('#Stadt_suche').keyup(showCity);
$('p').on(click, enterCity);


function showCity() {
    
    var str = SSI_GetValue('Stadt_suche'); // this function get the current value of the input-field
    
    if (str.length <= 2) {
        document.getElementById("dropdown-content").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("dropdown-content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", getcity.php?q=" + str + "%", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}


function enterCity(){
    var city = $(this).text();
    $("#Stadt_suche").val(city);
```

and- just in case it`s needed- the database query:

```
 <?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  exit('Could not connect');
}


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `Ort` FROM `HaendlernetzGesamt` WHERE `Ort` Like ?";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['q']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($ort);

if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        echo "<p id='" . $ort . "'>". $ort ."</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

The script is echoing the cities correctly, and the function enterCity works fine, if i dont try to define a variable (city), but set the value of the input field as a string (like "value("city")). But as the user has to select the entry, i can't give this input field a predefined value.

So- do you have any input what I could change to get the result im looking for?

Comment: Start by adding click handlers to those text paragraphs you are returning there (which should really rather be `li` inside a `ul` to begin with), so that the user _can_ make a "choice" here by clicking. And then, get the value from the clicked element, and set if for your input field.

Comment: `SSI_GetValue('Stadt_suche'); // this function get the current value of the input-field` - why would that need an extra function? `$(this).val()` should be able to get you that directly.